# Handle request in Google App Engine Task Queue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, task-queue

We are building analytics tool which collect events from web site and mobile apps. We want to process the request with Task queue in Google App engine. When i refer the doc in Google Developers site

```
 Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
 queue.add(withUrl("/analytics").param("id", String.valueOf(id)));
```

It has option to give only param. But how do i pass entire HTTP request to task queue and process them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the main problem here is how to pass all the request parameters **and** the request body to the task.

Unfortunately there is no simple "relay" or "redirect" method to move your request to the task queue (but it would be nice). You have to use the `Queue.add(TaskOptions taskOptions)` method to add your task.

The recommended way to instantiate a [TaskOptions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions) object is to statically import `TaskOptions.Builder.*` and invoke a static creation method followed by an instance mutator (if needed).

And use one of the following (or any other `payload()` methods):

```
TaskOptions.payload(byte[] payload);
TaskOptions.payload(byte[] payload, String contentType);
TaskOptions.payload(String payload);
```

to set the content of the request. You can get the payload by reading it from the `request.getInputStream()`.

The request parameters (if they are part of the URL and not the result of a form POST for example) you have to manually copy each with e.g. `TaskOptions.param(String name, String value)`.

Comment: +1 on "it would be nice" if you could redirect to a task queue. If all you really want to do is shove some data into a queue for later processing it's a bit cumbersome to have to build another request for it. Or better: I'd like to see task queues support lambdas and get away from the servlet implementation altogether.